# Getting system outofmemoryexception building string in vb

Tags: vb.net

I have a dataset that is with arround 30000records, so loping inside it and building the string fileStavki trows exeption, systemoutofmemmory. How can i solve this. Is working with arrays possible solution or something else?

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder    
For Each inRow In ds_in.Tables(0).Rows
                    rbr += 1
                    pisi_red = "2" & Enc3.prefill(rbr, "0", 6) & Share.RightPrefill(inRow("prioritet"), "0", 5)
                    pisi_red &= Enc3.prefill(Enc3.IsNull(inRow("smetka_davac"), "0"), "0", 15)
                    pisi_red &= Share.RightPrefill(Enc3.lat2kir(Enc3.IsNull(inRow("naziv_davac"), "")), " ", 70)
                    pisi_red &= Share.RightPrefill(Enc3.IsNull(inRow("povik_broj_davac"), ""), " ", 24)
                    pisi_red &= Share.RightPrefill(Enc3.lat2kir(Enc3.IsNull(inRow("cel_na_doznaka"), "")), " ", 70)
                    pisi_red &= Enc3.prefill(inRow("sif_tip_plakanje"), "0", 6)
                    pisi_red &= "+" & Enc3.prefill(FormatNumber(inRow("iznos"), 5, TriState.False, TriState.False, TriState.False), "0", 21)
                    pisi_red &= inRow("smetka_primac") & Share.RightPrefill(Enc3.lat2kir(Trim(inRow("naziv_primac"))), " ", 70)
                    pisi_red &= Share.RightPrefill(Enc3.IsNull(inRow("povik_broj_primac"), ""), " ", 24)
                    pisi_red &= inRow("tip_instrument") & Share.RightPrefill(Enc3.IsNull(inRow("broj_transakcija"), ""), " ", 16)
                    pisi_red &= inRow("sistem_poravnuva") & Enc3.prefill(Enc3.IsNull(inRow("edb"), ""), "0", 13)
                    pisi_red &= vbCrLf
                    sb.Append(pisi_red)
                    'fileStavki &= pisi_red
                Next
```

after this i have

```
 sw.Write(fileStavki)
        sw.Flush()
        sw.Close()
```

I think even if i use stringbuilder the string fileStavki will be build like this

```
filestavki = sb.ToString
```

And here i will also get outofmemory exeption

Comment: You need to introduce yourself to the `StringBuilder` class.

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` like @jmcilhinney suggested: Create *one* instance,  `Append()` all strings to it, call `ToString()` and assign it´s result to `fileStavki` and finally call `Clear` for the next `inRow`.

Comment: Updated the question with more detaiils

Comment: Fixed it as it is in the question, there is no problem at the line  filestavki = sb.ToString

Comment: Strings in .Net are immutable -- they cannot be changed.  Every one of your uses of  `&` creates a new string and copies the contents of the old string into it before appending the next string.  You are creating about 16 new strings every time this code is executed.  So for 30000 rows, you are creating approximately 480000 strings.  Using a `StringBuilder` as others have suggested is the better approach.